# Edit / Save a file owned by root in OS X

Tags: macos, permissions

Using [this](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_leopard.php) example Im trying to edit a root file - like `/private/etc/hosts` but when I click Unlock, it does not ask for the OS X password.

According to the link I should:

> Save the file. Because it's owned by
>   "root", you will be prompted to enter
>   your Mac password.

But when I try to save it, it keeps saying:

> This operation couldn't be completed because an error occurred.
>   You do not have sufficient privileges to perform this operation.
>   (MacOS Error Code : -5000)

Comment: Can't reproduce, works for me. Actually it should have asked you for the password when you clicked the "unlock" button, since the file belongs to `root` (and the `wheel` group). Saving should not prompt you for anything after you've authorized. If you need a quick fix you can run something like `sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /private/etc/hosts`, which will open TextEdit with the necessary privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file using 'sudo' from within the terminal.

```
sudo <your_text_editor> path/to/file
```

That should prompt you for your password and give you the necessary permissions required to save the file to disk.